# relation "django_admin_log" already exists

Tags: django

when i try to run `python manage.py migrate` i run into following error
[image]

Upon running `python manage.py run migrations` it says no changes detected. and when i runserver it gives me warning that i have unapplied migrations as well.i have been searching internet for two hours but got not solution. Someone knowing the solution please share :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `python manage.py makemigrations [app name]` and if still, this does detect changes then delete the folder named `migrations` which is inside your application folder and then use this `python manage.py makemigrations [app name]`. Once migration happens successfully do the `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 14):

The table in your database that stores migration data to keep track of what has been applied is out of date. Try running `python manage.py migrate --fake`

Comment: Solved id for me, when the accepted answer did not work. +1.

Answer (score 1):

## **Don't Try This at Home**

I faced this issue, i make two changes,

1. change AUTH_USER_MODEL, so i have one migraiton about it
2. second one add new field for my folder_model(migration name: `folder_model 0021`)

When my first migrate attempt(I already run makemigrations commands on local so i have migration files), it says;

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency account.0001_initial on database 'default'
```

This error reiases because i change the AUTH_USER_MODEL in the middle of the project, normally you have to remove your database and fresh start from the beginnig(also truncate migrations etc.), according to Django doc -> https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313

To fix this issue, you don't have to delete all migrations on db, just delete the migrations about `admin`(not from project just database)
[image]

After that just run

> python manage.py migrate

It throws `relation "django_admin_log" already exists`. For this issue, run:

> python manage.py migrate --fake

That's it, but not completely. Make fake migration act like you already make your all migrations successfully and save these on db. The issue came here that i have another migration about `folder_model 0021` and with fake migration it doesn't applied to my database table but saved to db_migrations table.

So fix this issue, delete the `folder_model 0021`to database migration table (just 0021 not all folder_model migrations).

After delete just run `python manage.py migrate`
Everything is fine!